# Tkinter text making the button move to sides

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I am trying to create a TicTacToe game in Tkinter and I am trying to put a label under the buttons of the board but when I am put the label under the buttons the buttons are moving to the sides.
how can I fix it?
this is my code:

```
    from tkinter import *
    from tkinter import messagebox
    root = Tk()
    root.title('TicTacToe')
    # X starts
    clicked = True
    count = 0
    #button clicked function
    def b_click(b):
        global clicked
        global count
        
        if b["text"] == " " and clicked == True:
            b["text"] = "X"
            clicked = False
            count += 1
        elif b["text"] == " " and clicked == False:
            b["text"] = "O"
            clicked = True
            count += 1
        else:
            messages["text"] = "you cant do that"
            
    #build the buttons
    b1 = Button(root, text=" ", font =("Helvetica", 20), height=3, width=6, bg="SystemButtonFace", command= lambda:b_click(b1))
    b2 = Button(root, text=" ", font =("Helvetica", 20), height=3, width=6, bg="SystemButtonFace", command= lambda:b_click(b2))
    b3 = Button(root, text=" ", font =("Helvetica", 20), height=3, width=6, bg="SystemButtonFace", command= lambda:b_click(b3))
    b4 = Button(root, text=" ", font =("Helvetica", 20), height=3, width=6, bg="SystemButtonFace", command= lambda:b_click(b4))
    b5 = Button(root, text=" ", font =("Helvetica", 20), height=3, width=6, bg="SystemButtonFace", command= lambda:b_click(b5))
    b6 = Button(root, text=" ", font =("Helvetica", 20), height=3, width=6, bg="SystemButtonFace", command= lambda:b_click(b6))
    b7 = Button(root, text=" ", font =("Helvetica", 20), height=3, width=6, bg="SystemButtonFace", command= lambda:b_click(b7))
    b8 = Button(root, text=" ", font =("Helvetica", 20), height=3, width=6, bg="SystemButtonFace", command= lambda:b_click(b8))
    b9 = Button(root, text=" ", font =("Helvetica", 20), height=3, width=6, bg="SystemButtonFace", command= lambda:b_click(b9))
    messages  = Label(root, text="", font =("Helvetica", 20), height=1, width=15, relief="sunken")
    space = Label(root, text="", font =("Helvetica",))
    #display the buttons
    b1.grid(row=0, column=0)
    b2.grid(row=0, column=1)
    b3.grid(row=0, column=2)
    
    b4.grid(row=1, column=0)
    b5.grid(row=1, column=1)
    b6.grid(row=1, column=2)
    
    b7.grid(row=2, column=0)
    b8.grid(row=2, column=1)
    b9.grid(row=2, column=2)
    space.grid(row=3, column=0)
    messages.grid(row=4, column=1)
    
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I assume that `messages` is the Label you're having problems with.  Since it exists only in column 1, it *cannot* extend underneath the Buttons in column 0, nor those in column 2; all it can do is push them to the sides.  You want it to be able to use the space of all three columns - `column=0, columnspan=3` for example.  Alternatively, you could put all the Buttons inside a Frame; you could then put widgets directly in the root window, outside of that Frame, so that they aren't constrained at all by the grid applied to the Buttons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you try to add the label under the buttons, if you don't specify the **columnspan** the label will take the whole cell, so what happened is that the label is wider than the buttons, and since it took all the cell the buttons went to the sides, so if you put it like this:

```
...
space.grid(row=3, column=0)
messages.grid(row=4, column=0, columnspan=3)

root.mainloop()
```

you are telling tkinter that your label is taking the three columns, and so it does not move the buttons anymore. Here's the result:

[image]